# Sytem.exit vs break or return

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am executing following ActiveMq program, to put the files in queues.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, IOException {
    FileInputStream in;
    //Write the file from some location that is to be uploaded on ActiveMQ server

    in = new FileInputStream("d:\\test-transfer-doc-1.docx");
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    "tcp://localhost:61616?jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl=http://admin:admin@localhost:8161/fileserver/");
    ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory
                    .createConnection();
    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue destination = session.createQueue("stream.file");
    OutputStream out = connection.createOutputStream(destination);

    // now write the file on to ActiveMQ
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int bytesRead=0;bytesRead!=-1;) {
            bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
            System.out.println("bytes read="+bytesRead);
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Now existiong from prog");
                //System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("sender\r\n");
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
    }
    System.out.println("After for loop");  
}
```

When the bytesRead == -1, I want to unload the program from JVM as its task is completed. For this purpose, I had initially, used `break` keyword, and its producing following output on Eclipse Console

[image]

using this, the program doesn't get unload form JVM, as the console RED button is still active.

Now I used, System.exit(0) for this purpose, and its exiting the program from the JVM. But I don't want to use System.exit(0) for this purpose. I tried to use simple void `return` too in place of `break` but its also not working.

Please tell why `break` and `return` aren't working in this case to end the program and why its still running?

Regards,

Arun

Comment: breaking will only exit from the loop. Close all the resources and break. Then your program should exit properly..

Comment: I don't see any reason why return is not exiting the main method and finally the JVM

Comment: Try and `.flush()` your `out`. Note however that your resources are not handled correctly, you should close() in `finally`.

Comment: did you try `connection.stop()` ? in place of `break` ?

Comment: Yes. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to close your resources (queues, inputstreams) since they can keep the program alive, after that a simple return will suffice to end the program.

Comment: can return be blocked by the resources? If the code has reached the return statement, then it should simply return, isnt?

Comment: If there are non-daemon threads running, only the main thread will finish. The process will still continue running until all threads have finished.

Answer (score 2):

Both return and break work. The problem is `that connection.start()`; starts a Thread (you can see it in debug mode under the name of [Active MQ Transport...]) and until there exists a running non-daemon thread JVM does not terminate unless System.exit is called.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the JVM still lingering could be some user thread is still hasn't finished. From a preliminary investigation I believe your Session internally runs a thread. I believe you should be stoppping your session and closing your connection before breaking. That should probably resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM runs as long as a non demon thread is running - so all the people above are correct: You have to close all the resources so the non-demon threads shutdown.